# Flutter Flame priority value is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, game-development, flame

I have SpriteComponent named Obstacle. I set the priority value to 0 in the super method. But the Obstacle component is regenerated with the update method. It disappears when it exits the screen. When it reoccurs, the priorty value becomes invalid. I am sharing sample screenshots.

[first img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsfuo.jpg)
[second img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpajB.jpg)

The player stays behind the obstacle. GameOverPanel always at the back.

```dart
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    add(ScreenHitbox());

    add(gameRef.homeBackgroundParallaxComponent);
    add(gameRef.homeBaseParallax);

    add(gameRef.obstacleManager..priority = 0);
    add(gameRef.playerManager..priority = 1);
    add(gameRef.gameOverPanel..priority = 2);
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    gameRef.obstacleManager.updateObstacle(GameConst.gameSpeed * dt);
    gameRef.playerManager.changePositionDown(value: GameConst.gravity * dt);
  }
```

- Game Over Panel

```dart
class GameOverPanel extends Component with HasGameRef<HopyBirdGame> {
  GameOverPanel() : super(priority: 4);

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    add(GameOverText());
  }

  @override
  void renderTree(Canvas canvas) {
    if (gameRef.gameOver) {
      super.renderTree(canvas);
    }
  }
}

class GameOverText extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef<HopyBirdGame> {
  GameOverText() : super(size: Vector2(300, 80), anchor: Anchor.center);

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    sprite = await gameRef.loadSprite(Assets.gameOver.path);
    position = Vector2(gameRef.screenWidth / 2, gameRef.screenHeight / 2);
    return super.onLoad();
  }
}
```

-Obstacle

```dart
class Obstacle extends SpriteComponent
    with HasGameRef<HopyBirdGame>, CollisionCallbacks {
  final ObstacleType obstacleType;

  Obstacle({
    required this.obstacleType,
    super.position,
    super.priority,
  }) : super(
          size: Vector2(GameConst.obstacleWidth, GameConst.obstacleHeight),
          anchor: Anchor.center,
        );

  Obstacle.empty({this.obstacleType = ObstacleType.empty});

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    switch (obstacleType) {
      case ObstacleType.up:
        sprite = await gameRef.loadSprite(
          Assets.redPipeUp.path,
        );

        break;
      case ObstacleType.down:
        sprite = await gameRef.loadSprite(
          Assets.redPipeDown.path,
        );

        break;

      case ObstacleType.empty:
        return;
    }

    add(RectangleHitbox());
  }
}
```

```dart
class Obstacles extends Component with HasGameRef<HopyBirdGame> {
  final Obstacle upObstacle;
  final Obstacle downObstacle;
  bool isCreateNextObstacles = true;

  Obstacles({
    required this.upObstacle,
    required this.downObstacle,
    super.priority,
  });

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() {
    upObstacle.priority = 1;
    downObstacle.priority = 1;
    createChildren();
    return super.onLoad();
  }

  void createChildren() {
    final children = [upObstacle, downObstacle];
    addAll(children);
  }
}
```

- Obstacle Manager

```dart
class ObstacleManager extends Component with HasGameRef<HopyBirdGame> {
  ObstacleManager() : super(priority: 1);
  ListQueue<Obstacles> history = ListQueue();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    createObstacles();
  }

  void updateObstacle(double value) {
    if (!gameRef.gameOver) {
      if (history.isNotEmpty) {
        history.last.upObstacle.position.x -= value;
        history.last.downObstacle.position.x -= value;
        if (history.last.upObstacle.position.x <= gameRef.screenWidth / 2) {
          createObstacles();

          final isThereAnyObstaclesOutsideScreen = history.any(
            (element) =>
                element.downObstacle.position.x <=
                -(GameConst.obstacleWidth / 2),
          );
          if (isThereAnyObstaclesOutsideScreen) {
            final obstaclesOutsideScreen = history
                .lastWhere((element) => element.downObstacle.position.x <= 0);

            obstaclesOutsideScreen.removeFromParent();
            gameRef.remove(obstaclesOutsideScreen);
          }
        }
        if (history.length >= 2) {
          history.elementAt(history.length - 2).upObstacle.position.x -= value;
          history.elementAt(history.length - 2).downObstacle.position.x -=
              value;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void createObstacles() {
    final obstaclesGap =
        gameRef.screenHeight - gameRef.difficulty.spaceForPlayers;
    final gapAboveTheObstacleOnScreen =
        ((2 * GameConst.obstacleHeight) - obstaclesGap) / 2;

    final randomNumber = _randomGenerator(
      min: -gameRef.difficulty.distanceAxisYToGoUpAndDown,
      max: gameRef.difficulty.distanceAxisYToGoUpAndDown,
    );

    final axisYOfUpObstacle = (GameConst.obstacleHeight / 2) -
        gapAboveTheObstacleOnScreen +
        randomNumber;

    final axisYOfDownObstacle = axisYOfUpObstacle +
        GameConst.obstacleHeight +
        gameRef.difficulty.spaceForPlayers;

    final obstacles = Obstacles(
      upObstacle: Obstacle(
        obstacleType: ObstacleType.up,
        position: Vector2(
          gameRef.screenWidth + (GameConst.obstacleWidth / 2),
          axisYOfUpObstacle,
        ),
      ),
      downObstacle: Obstacle(
        obstacleType: ObstacleType.down,
        position: Vector2(
          gameRef.screenWidth + (GameConst.obstacleWidth / 2),
          axisYOfDownObstacle,
        ),
      ),
    );

    history.add(obstacles);
    gameRef.add(obstacles);
  }

  double _randomGenerator({required double min, required double max}) {
    final gap = (max - min).toInt();
    return min + Random().nextInt(gap);
  }
}
```

EDIT: The same problem applies in game over panel.

- Game Over Panel

```dart
class GameOverPanel extends Component with HasGameRef<HopyBirdGame> {
  GameOverPanel() : super();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    add(GameOverText());
  }

  @override
  void renderTree(Canvas canvas) {
    if (gameRef.gameOver) {
      super.renderTree(canvas);
    }
  }
}

class GameOverText extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef<HopyBirdGame> {
  GameOverText()
      : super(
          size: Vector2(300, 80),
          anchor: Anchor.center,
        );

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    sprite = await gameRef.loadSprite(Assets.gameOver.path);
    position = Vector2(gameRef.screenWidth / 2, gameRef.screenHeight / 2);
    return super.onLoad();
  }
}
```

Similarly, the first assignment is made in the Flame Game class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (since the code for the `ObstacleManager` isn't present) that you are adding the obstacles directly to the game from the `ObstacleManager` to the component tree and that you aren't adding the `priority` to the actual `Obstacle` components.

If this is not the case, please update the question with the code for the `ObstacleManager`.

EDIT: After code upload.
It doesn't help that you are giving priorities to the manager classes when the components are not added as children to them, but to the `gameRef`. Since the player manager class isn't included in the question you either have to set the `Obstacles` to priority -1, or you have to give the player priority 1 (and obstacles will default to 0).

```dart
    gameRef.add(obstacles..priority = -1);
```

This will make the obstacles be behind the background, so you have to also change the background parallaxes:

```dart
    add(gameRef.homeBackgroundParallaxComponent..priority = -3);
    add(gameRef.homeBaseParallax..priority = -2);
```

So it will be better to just set the player priority to 1 where you are adding that one to the game, because then you don't have to change all the other classes.

Comment: I added the code of Obstacle, Obstacles and Obstacle Manager components. I tried changing the priority value here but it didn't work.

Comment: You are never setting the priority to the Obstacles component when it is added to the `gameRef` in the `ObstacleManager`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. How should i proceed? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is it correct to define all components in FlameGame class? In some cases I needed to access them and I decided to keep all the components there.

Comment: You can define fields for them in FlameGame, but can also query the children list to get out specific component types like this `children.query<Player>()`. Do note that the querying is not recursive.

Comment: I edited the question. Game over panel always stays in the background. Does adding this later in renderTree affect priority?

Comment: No, if it has an explicit priority it will follow that, but remember that priority only affects the render order of siblings, so components that have the same direct parent. A component that is further down the tree won't be compared with components at another level.